# Remove dates from String using RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, string, numbers

I have a string that looks like:

```
str_in = "Lemons: J2020, M2021. Eat by 9/03/28
    Strawberries: N2023, O2024. Buy by 10/10/20"
```

How do I get just `"J2020, M2021, N2023, O2024"`?

What I have so far is very hardcoded. It is:

```
str_in.replace("Lemon:","")
str_in.replace("Strawberries:", "")
str_in.replace("Buy by")
```

I don't know how to get rid of the date if the date changes from the number specified. Is there a RegEx form I could use?

Comment: good point, fixed that above. Can you help me figure out a solution that doesn't focus on the Strings to keep but rather the string to remove, pls? Sometimes I get values like JU2021" instead so it doesn't work to just do d{4}.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\d+/\d+/\d+', '', str_in)` should remove dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your original post and your follow-up comments, you can explicitly fetch the strings you want to keep by using this regex: `\b[A-Z]+\d+\b`. It allows for 1 or more letters followed by 1 or more digits, bounded as a single word. To test it and other regexes in the future, use [this great online tool](https://regex101.com/).

The `findall()` method on the regex class is best used here because it will return all instances of this pattern. For more on `findall()` and other kinds of matching methods, check out [this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html).

Putting all that together, the code would be:

```
values = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\d+\b', str_in)
```

Be sure to `import re` first.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your edited question, so, here's my edited answer

```
import re
re_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+),\s(\w+)\.')

data = [ 'Lemons: J2020, M2021. Eat by 9/03/28',
         'Strawberries: N2023, O2024. Buy by 10/10/20',
         'Peaches: N12345, O123456. Buy by 10/10/20'
        ]

for line in data:
    match = re_pattern.search(line)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1), match.group(2))
```

Comment: If your pattern is actually more complex, then please edit your question.

Comment: As others have said, it's difficult to pick what you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

string = "Lemons: J2020, M2021. Eat by 9/03/28 Strawberries: N2023, O2024. Buy by 10/10/20"

array = re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]\d{4}\b", string)

result = ','.join(array)
```

The result string is "J2020, M2021, N2023, O2024"

The array is ['J2020', 'M2021', 'N2023', 'O2024']

Answer (score 0):

The regex matches the possibility of having 1 OR 2 chars in the begining of the required text an then matches the later portions of the digits. I think the OP has the requisite information to make a test on the basis of this information.

```
import re

str_in = "Lemons: J2020, M2021. Eat by 9/03/28 \
    Strawberries: N2023, O2024. Buy by 10/10/20"

result = re.findall(r'([A-Z]{1,2}\d+)', str_in)

print(result)
```

Comment: I think I have provided a more complete answer now.